# App Domains Facebook

Tags: facebook-app-center

I get an error message the domain is not valid with the app domains form.  My website is in a folder underneath the direct domain as (mydomain.com/folder) and then I save the changes and get the error.  Now if I put in (mydomain.com) the domain is accepted on the facebook end but cant connect because it isnt the directory to the app or site.  Facebook apparently cant point to a specific folder (mydomain.com/folder) for app domains it can only point the direct domain (mydomain.com)  The facebook sign-in app Im using allows the callback url of http://mydomain.com/folder.  Is there a work around or a way to configure Facebook app settings in such a way to work with a domain such as (mydomain.com/folder) in regards to the app domains form field?